# Why is my Invoke-Command failing?

Tags: powershell

I am putting together a script that will check all of my web servers certificates so that I can monitor when they are set to expire.  When the script goes to execute the `Invoke-Command` I am getting this error:

[image: Invoke-Command Error Message]

Here is my code:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$results = @()
$ou = 'OU=test,OU=test,OU=Servers,DC=contoso,DC=com'

$subtree = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $ou -SearchScope Subtree -filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

ForEach($dn in $subtree){
    $servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $dn | select Name
    $results += $servers
}#ForEach($dn in $subtree)

$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create({
    Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:SSLBindings | ForEach-Object -Process `
        {
            If($_.Sites){
                $certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:LocalMachine/My |
                    Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -EQ -Value $_.Thumbprint

                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Sites                     = $_.Sites.Value
                        CertificateDNSNameList    = $certificate.DnsNameList
                        CertificateNotAfter       = $certificate.NotAfter
                    }#[PSCustomObject]
            }#If($_.Sites)
        }#Import-Module
})#ScriptBlock

ForEach($server in $results){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock | Select Sites,CertificateDNSNameList,CertificateNotAfter,PSComputerName #ScriptBlock       
}#ForEach($server in $results)
```

Now, If I take the following line out of the loop and replace `$server` with an actual server name, I get the results I am looking for:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock | Select Sites,CertificateDNSNameList,CertificateNotAfter,PSComputerName
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: well, obviously something is wrong with your server name, just check the array you are getting

Comment: I don't see where you are defining `$serverList`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin My apologies, I forgot to revert back to `$results` after testing another route.  I've edited the original post.

Comment: `Invoke-Command` (PowerShell remoting) doesn't use the obvious scope rules. I have an unreliable memory of something I read, which suggests that you might want to pass the server name as `$using:server`. See if you can find a reference to that syntax, and then try it; I'm _really_ not solid on this.

Comment: You want to `Select -ExpandProperty Name` otherwise it should be `Invoke-Command -Computername $server.name`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You would use `$using:` inside the `Invoke-Command` script block to use the variables from the parent scope. `$using` wouldn't apply to things not in scriptblock.

Comment: @BenH - Thanks; as I said, I'm _really_ not solid on that - our environment has PSRemoting disabled.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin `$using` applies to all scriptblocks not just when you use them over PSRemoting. But `Invoke-Command` is probably the most common use. So you may still find a use for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Results-Array is not an array of string, it is an array of object. Each object have the attribute name. Change your last ForEach-Loop into this and your script will work:

```
ForEach($server in $results){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.name -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock | Select Sites,CertificateDNSNameList,CertificateNotAfter,PSComputerName #ScriptBlock       
}#ForEach($server in $results)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like "select Name" is returning an object rather than a string. Try changing the line that fetches the servers to this:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $dn | select -ExpandProperty Name
```